# Is there a way to list process arguments as well using monit

Tags: linux, process, monit

I setup monit on Ubuntu 16.04.

```
sudo monit --version
This is Monit version 5.16
Built with ssl, with pam and with large files
```

For a given process, it currently lists below:

```
  status                            Running
  monitoring status                 Monitored
  pid                               8724
  parent pid                        8691
  uid                               0
  effective uid                     0
  gid                               0
  uptime                            6d 23h 36m 
  threads                           7
  children                          0
  memory                            190.6 MB
  memory total                      190.6 MB
  memory percent                    19.2%
  memory percent total              19.2%
  cpu percent                       6.8%
  cpu percent total                 6.8%
  data collected                    Sat, 07 Oct 2017 22:41:49
```

My question is that is there a way I can also list process arguments in this list? Basically, I would like to monitor not only matrices like uptime, load etc. but also what arguments the process is called and running with? Are there any other alternatives to monit that could provide a similar json based response?

Thanks.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -1):

There is a way to do what you want. On any Linux based system, you can use:

```
xargs -0 < /proc/<pid>/cmdline
```

Make sure you replace `<pid>` with your processes pid. That command will show the command that started the `pid` you inserted into that path, with args and all. You can even make a shell script to run monit and parse the pid section from the output and use that for xargs.

Comment: I know I can use even `ps -ef`. My question is specific to monit and similar tool. Basically, I don't want to login to the machine everytime. Just monitor via an external API.

Comment: I can write you a wrapper for monit that displays the start command with the regular monit stuff if you want. It would be probably be in python.

Comment: What does it take?

Comment: It wouldn’t take much. It could receive a pid argument or it could parse the monit output for the pid, or both, with the flag overriding the parse. It would also be able to pass any other non-pid arguments/flags on to the monit command.

Comment: So, will the output be available on monit http page as xml? (port 2812)

Comment: No. It would be in terminal.

Comment: basically, my requirements are very straight forward. I know which processes I want to see arguments for. So, if monit could just show those processes and those arguments in the xml on port 2812 - I am good. We could chat offline you want to understand what I am looking for.

Comment: I understand what you are looking for, but it would probably take more effort than it’s worth to do.

Comment: Submitted an [enhancement request](https://bitbucket.org/tildeslash/monit/issues/674/list-process-arguments-as-well)